# Android MediaRecorder won't record audio when in the background

Tags: android

I have been trying to get media recorder to work last couple of days.
I want when a user accepts a call, it starts recording the call.
Right now the recorder stops and starts correctly **but theres no audio** but the length is correct.

I just can get it to work when I put in for example on main activity or accessibility event directly. Or when I restart the app when a recording is ongoing.

I've tried a lot of things and no one worked. Any ideas? I've checked all permissions and are all OK, it records OK whenever its not being called from a broadcast receiver

```
public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "CallBr";

Bundle bundle;
String state;
String inCall, outCall;

private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: ");
    try {


        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
            if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);


                Intent newIntent = new Intent("com.test.audio_recorder.test");

                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                    newIntent.putExtra("startRecording", "startRecording");
                    context.sendBroadcast(newIntent);
                }

                Log.i(TAG, state);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
                    newIntent.putExtra("stopRecording", "stopRecording");

                    context.sendBroadcast(newIntent);

                    Log.i(TAG, "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
            if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Acessebility Service:

```
public class TService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String TAG = "TService";
    MediaRecorder audioRecorder;
    public boolean registered = false;


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "destroy");
        stopRecording();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent classname: " + accessibilityEvent.getClassName());
        try {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo node = accessibilityEvent.getSource();
            Log.i(TAG, "accessibilityEvent.getClassName:  " + accessibilityEvent.getEventType() + " " + accessibilityEvent.getClassName() + " " + accessibilityEvent.getEventType());
            AccessibilityNodeInfo currentNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
            AccessibilityNodeInfo info = accessibilityEvent.getSource();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent.getStringExtra("stop") == null) {
            createNotification();
            startRecording();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;

        }

        if(intent.getStringExtra("stop") != null) {
            stopRecording();
            stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;

        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();

        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED |
                AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;


        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;

        info.notificationTimeout = 100;

        this.setServiceInfo(info);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.test.audio_recorder.test");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        Log.i(TAG, "onServiceConnected: connected");

    }


    public void stopRecording() {
        Log.i(TAG, "stopRecording");
        if (audioRecorder != null) {
            audioRecorder.stop();
            audioRecorder.reset();
            audioRecorder.release();
            audioRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public void startRecording() {
        if (audioRecorder == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "startRecord");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(new Date());
            long time = currentTimeMillis();
            String str = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/D" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "M" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "T" + time + ".3gp";

            MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            AudioManager asd = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            Log.i(TAG, "startRecording: " + asd.getMode());
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setOutputFile(str);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            try {
                recorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
            }

            recorder.start();
            audioRecorder = recorder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    private void createNotification() {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("dasd")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentText("asdas").build();

        startForeground(1336, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE);
    }

    private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = (mr, what, extra) -> Log.i("TService",
            "Error: " + what + ", " + extra);

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onInterrupt");
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        private static final String TAG = "BRoadcastreceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "test");
            AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
            AccessibilityEvent event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
            event.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED);
            event.setClassName(getClass().getName());
            event.setPackageName(context.getPackageName());
            event.getText().add("asdasdasdasdasd");

            manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event);
            if (intent.getStringExtra("startRecording") != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
                Intent asd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class);
                asd.putExtra("start", "start");
                startForegroundService(asd);
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra("stopRecording") != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onStopCommand");
                Intent asd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TService.class);
                asd.putExtra("stop", "stop");
                startForegroundService(asd);
            }
        }


    };

}
```

MainActivity:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
        Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT,
        Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED,
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing AudioSource to VOICE_RECOGNITION fixed it.
Actually this only records the user microphone.